# How to redirect all the files in root only to another directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been looking for a while but I couldn't find anything similar. I have a website build with a diverse URL structure. Some of the URLs are from root, some other have various folders and paths. Now, I need to be able to redirect all paths from root to another folder, but keep a different structure for files from other folders

For example, this pattern:

- `/mypage` should redirect to `/anotherfolder/mypage/content.php`
- `/mysecondpage` should redirect to `/anotherfolder/mysecondpage/content.php`

In this example `mypage` and `mysecondpage` are variables to be passed to the destination.

But, for pages coming from another folder in root, I need another pattern at the destination. For example:

- `/somerootfolder/somepage` should redirect to `someotherfolder/somepage.php`

In this example, `somepage` is the pattern that should pass to the destination.

The second type of redirect should not alter the first and the viceversa.

What I did for the first directive (any files in root, but only in root should redirect to another folder) is:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /foldername/$1/content.php [L]
```

... where `$1` equals the name from `(.*)`. And this works very well by itself, holding the old URL but getting the contents from the other folder.

For the second directive (files from within a folder to another folder keeping the name and adding extension) I did:

```
RewriteRule ^foldername/(.*) /anotherfolder/$1.php [L]
```

... where `$1` equals `(.*)`. And everything inside `foldername` keeps its old URL but gets content from `anotherfolder`.

Everything works separately but not together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second rule matches the rewritten URL from the first rule, so gets rewritten a second time - to something malformed like `/anotherfolder/mypage/content.php.php`. If it wasn't for the condition on the first rule that checked against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, you would have a rewrite loop.

You would seem to be able to avoid the conflict (and *condition* on the *both* rules) just by making the regex more specific - you only want to match path segments in the root or the subdirectory, not *everything*.

Try the following instead:

```
# Rewrite root files to another folder
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /foldername/$1/content.php [L]

# Rewrite requests for /foldername/somepage to /anotherfolder
RewriteRule ^foldername/([^/]+)$ /anotherfolder/$1.php [L]
```

By making the regex more *restrictive* we have avoided the conflict.